# Counting records with single and multiple categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these records in my table

```
researchID | category
      19        math
      20        math
      21        math
      22        math
      22        history
      23        math
      23        english
      24        math
      24        english
```

with this query: SELECT researchID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category_id SEPARATOR "|") as category FROM `tbl_submission_categories` GROUP BY researchid. my result is this

```
 researchID | category
      19        math
      20        math
      21        math
      22        math|history
      23        math|english
      24        math|english
```

but the result that i want is this

```
research_count | category
      3           math
      1           math|history
      2           math|english
```

what sql query do i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by moving you query in inner clause and apply aggregation on the result set of inner query

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) research_count 
FROM(
    SELECT researchID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category_id SEPARATOR "|") as category 
    FROM tbl_submission_categories 
    GROUP BY researchid
) t
GROUP BY category
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b604e/2)

Comment: may i ask what the t is for?

Comment: `t` is an alias for inner clause you can give it some other name

Comment: so it can be anything?

Comment: Yes its just a name for more information have a look [Alias (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL))

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional subquery:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT researchID,
             GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category_id ORDER BY category_id SEPARATOR '|') as category 
      FROM tbl_submission_categories
      GROUP BY researchid
     ) sc
GROUP BY category;
```

You will notice one important difference from your query.  The `GROUP_CONCAT()` has an `ORDER BY`.  This is important, because `GROUP_CONCAT()` does not guarantee the ordering within the result.  To ensure the same ordering, you need `ORDER BY`.